# Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3 and MySQLl 5.5 on Linux Mint 17?

Tags: linux-mint, apt, apache-httpd, php

Our stack consists of Apache 2.2, PHP 5.3 and MySQL 5.5. I've installed Linux Mint 17 Giana. If I install `apache2` via `apt`, it will install Apache 2.4 which is not required for me.

Is there any way to install Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.3 via `apt` by changing canonical repository?